# How to have a powerup have a slight chance of spawning when killing an enemy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so we have a class assignment and pretty much we are doing the Survival Shooter project from the Unity tutorials. I've managed to make health packs and little boxes that give you speed when you pick them up, but now I want the power-ups to have a slight chance of dropping when enemies die. Can someone help me out? I'm not really asking for entire code, I have some down below:

```
 public float percentDrop = 50f;
 public GameObject HealthPack;
 void Awake()
 {
     HealthPack = GetComponent<GameObject>();
 }
public void TakeDamage (int amount, Vector3 hitPoint) { if(isDead) return;

     enemyAudio.Play ();
     currentHealth -= amount;

     hitParticles.transform.position = hitPoint;
     hitParticles.Play();
     if(currentHealth <= 0)
     {
         Death ();
     }
 }
 void Death ()
 {
     isDead = true;
     capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;
     anim.SetTrigger ("Dead");
     enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
     enemyAudio.Play ();

     var randChance = Random.Range(0f, 100f);
     if (randChance < percentDrop)
     {
         //GameObject.Healthpack.setActice(true);           
     }
 }
```

I'm not too sure how to make the Game Object spawn when they die, can someone help me out?

Comment: You'll want to find a tutorial about Unity's `Instantiate` function. Unfortunately, recommending a specific tutorial is out-of-scope for Stack Overflow, but I promise there are tons of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a "Health Pack" prefab from the editor. If you need more information about prefabs, the information is out there on the web. To create a prefab, simply drag and drop a GameObject from the scene to your project. Its name in the scene will become blue. You can delete it from the scene and it will still be in the project.
2. Drag the prefab from the project to the HealthPack slot in the inspector of your ennemy. The ennemy will now have a reference to the prefab.
3. When you want to create a new health pack, you can use the Object.Instantiate static method as specified by rutter. [Here is the official doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). When you instantiate your new Health Pack, I guess you want it to appear where the ennemy is, wich means you'll want to use one of the method's overloads which takes a `Vector3D position` as a parameter, which will most likely be `transform.position`. Since those methods also ask for a Quaternion, just pass in the `Quaternion.identity` constant.

This is how your code could look:

```
 if (randChance < percentDrop)
 {
     Object.Instantiate(HealthPack, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);           
 }
```

Another problem, as mentioned in my comment, is the Awake function: `HealthPack = GetComponent<GameObject>();`.
The HealthPack prefab should be assigned to the ennemy from the inspector. That line in the Awake function will assign your ennemy's `GameObject` component to `HealthPack`, which is not desirable in the current context.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I had a health pack prefab and we had started to learn about setActive functions but I just couldn't figure out how to make it work for this scenario. I'll be sure to check out the Instantiate function!

Comment: When I try to put Transform.position in the Vector 3 parameters, Unity doesn't seem to like that... Any idea why?

Comment: I wrote `Transform.position` when it should have been `transform.position`. My bad.

Comment: Oh, and you should remove that Awake method.

Comment: Now it is saying "Vector3 does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"... I'm sorry to be bothering you if there is any problem it's just I'm fairly new to Unity especially bigger projects like this.

Comment: Okay thank you! For some reason though now the healthpacks keep on spawning every time an enemy dies...

Comment: This is what I have so far: (at least what is important for this part)

    public float percentDrop = 50f;
    public GameObject HealthPack;

        var randChance = Random.Range(0f, 100f);

        if (randChance < percentDrop)
        {
            Object.Instantiate(HealthPack, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);         
        }

Comment: In the original question, I don't see `isDead` being declared. Maybe something about `TakeDamage()` being called avery time you hit the corpse because of that? You might also want to destroy the ennemy GameObject when he disapeared. Anyway, I think the problem is something else and not linked to the instantiation. You might want to investigate or ask another question on stackoverflow, providing more context.